# Unable to test a method using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine

How to test the return value of `dialog.button` in Jasmine?

```
angular.module('employer').factory('popFactory', function($window) {
  var dialog = {};
  dialog.button = function(){
    $window.location.href = 'tel:' + dialog.number;
    return $window.location.href;
  };
};
```

I have tried the following unit tests in Jasmine with no luck,

1)

```
it('should check for a value', function(){
  spyOn(dialog, 'button');
  expect(dialog.button).toEqual('tel:' + dialog.clientNumber);
});
```

Console Error: `Expected spy on button to equal 'tel:1234566789'.`

2)

```
it('should check for a value', function(){
      spyOn(dialog, 'button');
      expect(dialog.button()).toEqual('tel:' + dialog.clientNumber);
    });
```

Console Error: `Expected undefined to equal 'tel:1234566789'.`

What am I doing wrong?

`display.test.js` - Spec

I am posting only a part of my spec because it is really big and contains a lot of test cases.

```
describe('employer', function () {
  beforeEach(module('employer'));

  describe('factory: dialog', function() {
    var dialog = null;
    var rootScope, ionicPopup, windowMock, authenticationFactory, restfulService, brandingMock;

    beforeEach(inject(function(popFactory, $rootScope, $ionicPopup, $state, $window, authentication, restfulService, branding) {
      dialog    = popFactory;
      rootScope       = $rootScope;
      ionicPopup      = $ionicPopup;
      state           = $state;
      windowMock      = $window;
      authenticationFactory = authentication;
      restfulServiceMock         = restfulService;
      brandingMock  = branding;
    }));

    it('initializes', function () {
      expect(dialog.investigateNumber).toBe('');
      expect(dialog.alertingNumber).toBe('');
      expect(dialog.mirrorNumber).toBe(''); //All these tests pass
      expect(dialog.contactNumber).toBe('');
      expect(dialog.client).toBe(brandingMock.client);
      expect(dialog.currentCall).toEqual(dialog.alertNumber);
      expect(dialog.phone).toBe(brandingMock.phone);
    });

    it('logs', function () {
      spyOn(console, 'log');
      var err = 'test error';
      dialog.logError(err);
      expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(err);
    });

    it('canceling passcode', function(){
      var title = 'title';
      spyOn(ionicPopup ,'show');
      dialog.confirmCancelPasscode(title);
      expect(ionicPopup.show).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('title-based alert', function(){
      var title = 'testing-title';
      spyOn(ionicPopup, 'show');
      dialog.showTitleAlert(title);
      expect(ionicPopup.show).toHaveBeenCalled()
    });

    it('generic alert', function(){
      var title = 'test-title';
      spyOn(ionicPopup, 'show');
      dialog.showGenericAlert(title);
      expect(ionicPopup.show).toHaveBeenCalled()
    });

    it('two-button alert', function(){
      var title = 'test-title';
      var message = 'test-message';
      var affirmativeText = 'test-affirm';
      var denyText = 'test-deny';
      var affirmation = function(){};
      var denyingAccess = affirmation;
    })
   };
```

Comment: can you post what you see in your terminal? Also, in both examples, you are calling `dialog.button()` twice. You can remove the first instance of `dialog.button();`.

Comment: @dannypaz I have edited my question to list the console errors I am getting. Thank you.

Comment: can you paste your entire test file including setup. Also, your code for `.factory` looks incorrect. it should be `angular.module('employer').factory('myFactoryName', function($window){});` ect.

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation on factories](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) for more examples

Comment: I have edited my question to include the test file. My factory is declared and instantiated correctly, as my application is running as expected without any errors.

Comment: @dannypaz My factory is declared correctly just the way you mentioned earlier. I made a typo in the SO question.